# Pushwoosh iOS integration

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning, pushwoosh, mobileprovision

I have a Pushwoosh premium account and so I configured iOS notifications automatically and downloaded the Provisioning profile via the link. I added the mentioned provisioning profile to my iPhone Provisioning Profiles via Xcode 5.0.2 Organizer. I followed the steps to use Pushwoosh in my iOS application.

When I run the application, I receive the following message:

Pushwoosh Error Your provisioning profile does not have APS entry. Please make your profile push compatible.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It means the XCode still picks up "non push compatible" provisioning profile. The easiest way to check is to open the mobileprovisioning profile in text editor and look for "aps-environment" string. It should be there.

When you add new profile to XCode, it sometimes still picks the old one, so it might make sense to delete the old profile via Organizer in XCode.

I hope it helps!